# Find Cell HeaderName in openXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I m using OfficeOpenXML to import Excel data into Database. here is the code sample that I am using for my task.But I want to have HeaderName while looping through each cell in row As I have to make some modifications to columns.
Any help suggestion appreciated. Thanks!

```
 var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
 var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage();
for (var rowNum = 3; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
    {
      var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, DtCommon.Tables[0].Columns.Count-1];
      var row = tblResult.NewRow();
       foreach (var cell in wsRow)
          {
             row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text; //Find HeaderName here based on cell index
           }
      tblResult.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Comment: Please write if by "*header*" You mean value of first cell in each of the columns or something else.

Comment: Yes I mean first cell of the columns

Comment: By looking at Your code, I suppose You're using *ExcelPackage* library, is this correct? If so, I suppose You may be able to get value of the first cell in each column by writing `ws.Cell(1, cell.Column)` in the loop. I haven't tested this though, I'm just looking at the source code of hte *ExcelPackage* library.

Comment: Changed foreach loop to for loop . ExcelRange Header = ws.Cells[1, i]; used this and worked for me! Accessing value from Header.Value thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :). I'm just curious if the method I decribed worked as well.

Comment: Yes it did work for me

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted this suggestion in the comments, but as it helped, I'm posting it as an answer.

By looking at Your code, I suppose You're using *ExcelPackage* library.

If so, I suppose You may be able to get the first cell in each column by writing:

```
foreach (var cell in wsRow)
{
    // code to get the header cell
    var header = ws.Cell(1, cell.Column);

    // rest of your code here
    // ...
}
```